# Kendo virtual element binding? (like knockout)

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, data-binding, kendo-ui, telerik

After a quick Google and SO search, I'm guessing not, but...

Is there any way to do a virtual binding with kendo's MVVM?

In most cases with binding you have an element to bind to. For example:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">...</div>
```

...but in same cases you don't want one. Knockout allows to do something like this :

```
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <!-- ko foreach: items -->
  <li>...</li>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <li>Last</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to do this with kendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some additional searching and consulting, it seems that Kendo's MVVM bindings are a bit lacking.

The proper way to do these things in kendo appears to be in using templates.
(also Kendo's equivalent of knockouts "foreach" seems to be "source:" coupled with a template.)

The example written above might look like this:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  # for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { #
  <li>#= items[i] #</li>
  # } #
  <li>Last</li>
</ul>
</script>
```

This is the best I've found.